# Helper Dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

Can someone tell me how I can design this type of helper dialog? There will be question mark and near to that i have to show this type of information in a view.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tooltip class and decorate it : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html

Or use a lib like those two :

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_introduction_tooltip

https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip